# Unity 3D onClick or Input.touchCount not working

Tags: input, unity-game-engine, onclick

We have a little problem. When we use

```
 if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    Debug.Log(Input.touchCount.ToString());
```

we always get a zero. What is wrong?

Or when we use

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnMouseDown() {
        Application.LoadLevel("SomeLevel");
    }
}
```

it is not working too. We want to skip to another scene only on click anywhere.

Comment: read tags, it's not `unity`. use `unity3d`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a button and make it invisible and add this function

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class btnAction : MonoBehaviour {

  public void PlaybtnClicked(string SceneNumber){
      Application.LoadLevel (SceneNumber);
  }

}
```

don't forget to make the button big enough to cover the whole screen . it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me: my game stopped recognizing touch input, and it seemed to be right after installing the Input System. **I closed Unity, deleted the Library folder in my project, then restarted Unity.** Touch input works again now.

Answer (score -1):

> [OnMouseDown](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) is called when the user has pressed the mouse button while
>   over the GUIElement or Collider.

if i understand your question properly you need to use `Input.touchCount` in `Update` function. Like:

```
void Update() {
   if (Input.touchCount > 0)
       Debug.Log(Input.touchCount.ToString());     
}
```